# Bulletin and Fliers, looking for templates

Tags: templates

I need to make a few standard fliers to hang up on our department wall, the kind where you slap together a heading and an abstract and a picture. I could put together something myself but I could see this being a project that would easily consume more time then I'd prefer (being nit-picky about typographical style, and obsessing over spacings).  Are there any style-sheets or packages you've come across that produce good-looking, minimal fuss fliers in LaTeX?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like the memoir package with xelatex for that. In memoir there is an option that is something like `extrafontsizes` which will provide very font sizes up to 72 pt. Set your margins to something fairly small (1/2in all around maybe?), mix in a few `\minipage` commands, and you should be on your way. xelatex will provide you access to your system fonts.

I have a decent Epson printer that prints 13x19 in. I usually start like this:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[60pt, letterpaper, oneside, extrafontsizes]{memoir}

\usepackage[margin=1in, paperwidth=19in, paperheight=13in]{geometry}

\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine C}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text,Ligatures={Common}]{Linux Libertine}

\begin{document}

This is my flier

\includegraphics[width=10in]{some-fig.jpg}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Shouldn't Documentclass be lower case?